# Initializing a Module Class in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a module with a bunch of classes, one of the classes looks like this:

```
module ModularModule
  class ClassyClass

    def initialize(host, user, pass)
      $jenkins = JenkinsApi::Client.new(:server_ip => host, \
                         :username => user, \
                         :password => pass, \
                         :ssl => true, \
                         :server_port => 443)
    end

    ...

  end
end
```

I try and initialize the class like this:

```
ModularModule::ClassyClass.new(JENKINS_HOST, JENKINS_USER, JENKINS_PASS)
```

And I get this:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0)
```

I can see it's something to do with the "wrong" initialize being called, but I can't then see how I'm supposed to create a new instance of my class?

Comment: The code above is fine, you are calling `new` properly. The error is induced.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** The code above is fine, and should work for whoever's reading this.

Oh my me. Sorry, I posted this in frustration after over an hour of hair pulling, but it turned out to be something ridiculous.

I had `require ClassyClass` in the code I was calling it from, which was correctly pulling in the old code from the installed Gem, but I wanted to call the *changed* code (with the addition of the arguments to `initialize`) with `require_relative path/to/new/code`.

Sorry! :P